# How can I list all tests using `mix test`

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ex-unit

Is there a command-line invocation I can used in conjunction with `mix` that will output all test names without running the tests?

Comment: I think there is not, such command, but you can list all test names with `grep -h "test " ./test/**/*.exs | sed -e 's/do$//g'`

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question but for your future reference you can find command line switches for `mix test` by typing `mix help test`

Comment: To add to Oleksandr, you can [create your own custom mix tasks](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/mix-tasks#section-creating-our-own-mix-tasks) and implement the `run/1` function.

Answer (score 3):

This will still run the tests:

`mix test --trace`

Found in the `mix help test` page

**EDIT**: Didn't see the bit saying 'without running the tests', but I thought it might be helpful

Comment: This is also useful to see which tests are running if you've excluded a bunch of them, e.g. if you use tags then run `mix test --only my_tag_name --trace` to see which ones have been excluded and which have been run.